# Swiftmailer - get attachment content

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Is there a method to get the content of the Attachment to a message?

I have tried $message->getBody() to no avail.

Comment: you created the message - so you should already have it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$message->toString()` which contains the contents of the attachments.